# Get the current iteration path from TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to get the current iteration path for the teams TFS project. The way I'm trying to do this is by using the blog from http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/tfs11-api-reading-the-team-configuration-iterations-and-areas/ . I start by getting the team configurations from the following code:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TFSConncetion(@"http://tfs/url");
        var configSvc = tpc.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();
        var configs = configSvc.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(projectUri);
```

The problem with this is that my configs is always null, even though I'm a member of the team. I'm positive my projects URI is correct as well. After this I would get the team settings and use that to display the current iteration path.

```
TeamSettings ts = config.TeamSettings;
Console.WriteLine(ts.CurrentIterationPath);
```

Even if this didn't work I can still query the iteration dates from the team setting to get the one iteration that has a start date before today and finish date after today. The main problem is that I can't get my TeamSettingsConfigurationService to return anything but null when I try to get the team configurations with my projects URI.

Comment: I don't see where you used the `WebClient`.

Comment: The WebClient was used later in the code to download an image from TFS using the current iteration path. In this question I see now that it is unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the answer myself without using TeamSettingsConfigurationService at all. Here's how I did it:

```
    private static XmlNode currentIterationNode;
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = TFSConncetion(@"http://tfs/url");

    ICommonStructureService4 css = tpc.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();;
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = new WorkItemStore(tpc);

        foreach (Project teamProject in workItemStore.Projects)
        {
            if (teamProject.Name.Equals("TeamProjectNameGoesHere"))
            {
                NodeInfo[] structures = css.ListStructures(teamProject.Uri.ToString());
                NodeInfo iterations = structures.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StructureType.Equals("ProjectLifecycle"));

                if (iterations != null)
                {
                    XmlElement iterationsTree = css.GetNodesXml(new[] { iterations.Uri }, true);
                    XmlNodeList nodeList = iterationsTree.ChildNodes;
                    currentIterationNode = FindCurrentIteration(nodeList);
                    String currentIterationPath = currentIterationNode.Attributes["Path"].Value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where currentIterationPath is the current iteration path from TFS. The key to doing this was to get the NodeInfo[] array of structures and the NodeInfo iterations from these two lines of code I got from chamindacNavantis https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b785ae7-66c0-47ee-a6d2-c0ad8a3bd420/tfs-get-iteration-dates-metadata?forum=tfsgeneral:

```
    NodeInfo[] structures = css.ListStructures(teamProject.Uri.ToString());
    NodeInfo iterations = structures.FirstOrDefault(n => n.StructureType.Equals("ProjectLifecycle"));
```

After that I created an xml with nodes of every iteration inside the team project. These nodes also have the start date and end dates of each iteration. So I checked each node for a start date before DateTime.Now and finish date after DateTime.Now, which is all FindCurrentIteration(nodeList) does. 
And that will give you the current iteration node.

Answer (score 4):

There must be something wrong with your server connection or the project uri you're passing as the other code looks okay.

Maybe try something like this:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://server:8080/tfs/collection"),
                          new System.Net.NetworkCredential(tfsUserName, tfsPassword));
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

[Connect to Team Foundation Server from a Console Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx)

There is a good sample here which you can download (WPF client) and it will allow you to select a server connection, Team Project and Team:

[TFS API Part 46 (VS11) – Team Settings](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2012/05/23/tfs-api-part-46-vs11-team-settings/)

You can step through it and check the values you're passing into your code.

The sample gets the team configuration information is the same way you have in your code.

```
TeamSettingsConfigurationService teamConfig = tfs.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();
    var configs = teamConfig.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { projectInfo.Uri });
```

Once you have the collection of `TeamConfiguration` items then you need `TeamSettings.CurrentIterationPath`

Comment: I agree wit you @rerwinRR that something may have been wrong with my project uri, but I actually was using Shai Raiten's Blog to cross check the values of the uri's. I'm positive my server connection was ok. I did find a way to do this without using the TeamSettingsConfigurationService, and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've found to do it was by using `ICommonStructureService4` and `TeamSettingsConfigurationService` methods:

```
static TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
    .GetTeamProjectCollection("<tfsUri>")

(...)

static string GetCurrentIterationPath()
{
    var css = _tfs.GetService<ICommonStructureService4>();

    var teamProjectName = "<teamProjectName>";
    var project = css.GetProjectFromName(teamProjectName);

    var teamName = "<teamName>";
    var teamSettingsStore = _tfs.GetService<TeamSettingsConfigurationService>();

    var settings = teamSettingsStore
        .GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { project.Uri })
        .Where(c => c.TeamName == teamName)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (settings == null)
    {
        var currentUser = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            $"User '{currentUser}' doesn't have access to '{teamName}' team project.");
    }

    return settings.TeamSettings.CurrentIterationPath;
}
```